# Adding new item wizard (in 2 steps)

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-views

I'd like to make `Save` button in Django admin page to not redirect back to the page where I clicked `Add` button, but to go to my template. There are some fields in my template that should be filled and the result has to be sent back to server.

In my `admin.py` I redefined `response_add` which is called when a new entry is being created in DB.

`admin.py`:

```
def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue='../%s/'):
    #save the entry in DB
    super(MyModelAdmin, self).response_add(request, obj, post_url_continue)

    #To second step -- template 
    return self.second_step(request, obj)
```

`views.second_step`:

```
def second_step(self, request, obj):
    #make something with obj
    #get some obj fields as params (list)

#When cancel button clicked in template's form
if 'cancel' in request.POST:
    self.message_user(request, _(u'Canceled'))
    return

#When saveparams button clicked in template's form
elif 'saveparams' in request.POST:
    for p in params:
        #p.value is models.CharField
        #request.POST['p.name'] -- inputted by user in template's form
        p.value = request.POST[p.name]
        p.save()

    msg = "%s. Success;" % (obj)
    self.message_user(request, "%s" % msg)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())

return render_to_response('template.html', {'obj': obj, 'params': params, \
                                                    'path':  request.get_full_path()})
```

`template.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form method="post" action="{{ path }}"> 
        <p>
            {% for p in params %}
                <input type="text" name="{{ p.name }}" />
            {% endfor %}

            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="second_step" />
            <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
            <input type="submit" name="saveparams" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

The **problem**:
I cannot "catch" the form's submit POST.
How can I get on server-side the (`<input type="text" name="{{ p.name }}" />`) value that has been submitted by user?

Comment: Try changing `p.value = request.POST['p.name'].value` to `p.value = request.POST[p.name]` (i guess it's the place where you want to get the value, right?)

Comment: @ilvar, yup, you're right. Edited my post

Comment: Looks same for me - still wrong dict key.